# Google Compute Startup Script PHP Files From Bucket

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine

I'd like to automatically load a folder full of php files from a bucket when an instance starts up. My php files are normally located at `/var/www/html`

How do I write a startup script for this?

I think this would be enormously useful for people such as myself who are trying to deploy autoscaling, but don't want to have to create a new image with their php files every time they want to deploy changes. It would also be useful as a way of keeping a live backup on cloud storage.